# Auto approve the step if the submitter is the approver

Tags: approval-process, approval-step, approval-history

I got a requirement to auto approve a step if the approver in that step is the submitter of the Approval Process. But I dont see any Option to set like "Approve and go to Next Step" (Please suggest if there is any workaround for this). Its either next step or Approve Record. So I have decided to skip the step if the approver as same as submitter. So I have written entry criteria for steps to proceed only if the current approver is not equal to initial submitter else go to next step.

This is working but If the Initial Submitter is equal to Approver in step 1 then record is getting auto rejected.

[image]

Above is the screenshot of my approval steps.